# Vim: split specific filetype by default

Tags: vim, git-commit, ftplugin

When editing Git commits in Vim, I'd like to automatically split the window on open so that I can edit the commit message in the top pane while keeping the commit change list in the bottom panel.

I have the ftplugin with a gitcommit.vim file for setting some other Git-commit-specific options, but when I add `split` to it, I get 3 panes (presumably because the second pane *also* splits, and then something prevents further recursion into infinity?).

I'd also like it to switch to the second panel and move the line that says `# Changes to be committed:` to the top of the buffer for when I am doing commit-amends and the message is already long. Then, I'd like it to move back to the top buffer. I know what to type to do that, but I'd like it to happen automatically, if possible.

Comment: Did you check [fugitive plugin?](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive)

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly? You want to split the commit window (`<c-w>s`), go to the new split via `<c-w>j` then do a search `/^# Changes<cr>`, scroll that line to the top (`zt`), and then switch back to the top split `<c-w>k`?

Comment: @PeterRincker: Yes, but how do I send those commands from the ftplugin .vim configuration for Git commits?

Comment: Although this does not answer the question: you might want to try [rhysd/committia.vim](https://github.com/rhysd/committia.vim) too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a command to put in your `~/.vim/ftplugin/gitcommit.vim` file:

```
command! -buffer -nargs=0 Changes :execute "normal! \<c-w>s\<c-w>jgg"<bar>call search('^# Changes')<bar>execute "normal! zt\<c-w>p"
```

This provides `:Changes` command which does what you want. I hesitate to have it fire off immediately as for most commits I doubt you will need this functionality.

I also agree with @mMontu that you should check out [Fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) as well as this [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) post: [The Fugitive Series - a retrospective](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2011/05/the-fugitive-series/).